# print line by line memory consumed in python scripts to detect memory leakage

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks

I have a complicated code but i want to trace memory leakage in some while loop. A sample code is as below in which i want to print memory(in MB/KB) used by `data` object in each iteration, as data might change, the memory consumed may vary accordingly. I tried looking into tracemalloc and memory_profiler but could not print line by line memory consumption:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import yfinance as yf
while True:
    data = yf.download(tickers='UBER', period='5d', interval='1m')
    # print memory consumed by variable data in MB
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: You can get the size of any python variable with `sys.getsizeof(object)`. With pandas you can also do `data.memory_usage()` to get the size of each column.

Comment: i am looking for memory leakage and the object need not be a pandas,so looking for a generic way of identifying memory usage by any python object

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://pythonspeed.com/datascience/#measuring-memory-usage

Comment: does not work for windows unfortunately

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` is the generic way